# gzip not working on internal css and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, css, gzip, http-compression

I followed this [link](http://betterexplained.com/articles/how-to-optimize-your-site-with-gzip-compression/) to gzip my php driven website It's working fine but what happened is I checked my website in this link `http://gzipwtf.com/` and as well as checked it in web developer toolbar in mozila whether css and javascripts are gzipped or not, I found only external css and javascripts are gzipped while internal css and javascripts are not gzipped. I have no idea what went wrong.

UPDATE:

Internal CSS and javascript such as `http://www.myserver.com/style.css` are not gzipped
while external css and javascipt such as `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js` are gzipped.

Comment: your hosting may not support gzip - check this first

Comment: i don't think that's the problem because i have tested my website with this tool http://www.gidnetwork.com/tools/gzip-test.php and it shows positive result

Comment: @Znarkus I think so but how do we confirm it? got any tools to check that?

Comment: I believe you can check if there is a `Content-Encoding: gzip` response header

Comment: @Znarkus I've checked it with firefox addons it's there

Comment: If the HTML is gzipped, how is the "internal css and js" not gzipped? What is "internal css and js"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery JS is loaded from Google's servers, which gzips it. You need to configure your server to gzip the static files (JS/CSS) on your server.

Do a Google search on "[insert server name] gzip", and you'll probably find countless tutorials :)